deleting realm instructions unclear
I was not able to make 'uuid' work in my _id, so I changed it to objectId and got:
[Error: The following changes cannot be made in additive-only schema mode:
Property 'Produit._id' has been changed from 'uuid' to 'object id'. If your app is running in development mode, you can delete the realm and restart the app to update your schema.]
I tried the troubleshooting, I tried
  const realm = useRealm();
  realm.write(() => {
    // Delete all objects from the realm.
    realm.deleteAll();
  });

I went as far as;
const app = new Realm.App({ id: '<app id here>' });

const realm = await Realm.open({ schema: [Produit]});

Realm.App.Sync.initiateClientReset(app, realm.path);

realm.write(() => {
  realm.deleteAll();
});

const syncConfigWithClientResetFallback = {
  flexible: true,
  clientReset: {
    mode: 'recoverOrDiscardUnsyncedChanges', // or "recoverUnsyncedChanges"
    // can also include `onBefore` and `onAfter` callbacks
    onFallback: (_session, path) => {
      try {
        const didUserConfirmReset = showUserAConfirmationDialog();
        if (didUserConfirmReset) {
          // Close and delete old realm from device
          realm.close();
          Realm.deleteFile(path);
          // Perform client reset
          Realm.App.Sync.initiateClientReset(app, path);
        }
      } catch (err) {
      }
    },
  },
};

export default function App() {
 
  return (
    <AppProvider id={'(app id)'}>
    <UserProvider fallback={LogIn}>
      <RealmProvider
        schema={[Produit]}
        sync={syncConfigWithClientResetFallback/*{
          flexible: true,
          initialSubscriptions: {
            update(subs, realm) {
              subs.add(realm.objects(Produit));
            },
          },
        }*/}>
    <Create/>

    </RealmProvider>
    </UserProvider>
    </AppProvider>
  )
}```
after that it just starts saying; [Error: Exception in HostFunction: Compiling JS failed: 26:21:';' expected Buffer size 8428 starts with: 5f5f642866756e6374696f6e2028676c]

and refuses to load. I am at my wit's end.



Alternatively, if any of you know how to make uuid work, I'd welcome that too, because that page is useless. https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-get-random-values

Thank you in advance!


This process can be confusing at first. The important thing to remember is you're actually working with two databases; a local database and then a database on the server. Certain actions 'break' the structure of either database; deleting a property, changing a property name etc. While other changes, like adding a property are non-breaking aka a 'additive' change. Breaking changes require a client reset - essentially re-syncing the server to the client. Please review Change Object Model
